# Is there way to know Android application were bought or downloaded from other site?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

For example user may download application from site or another Android device (and another Google account).
Now I learning Android LVL (License Verification Library). This way can say about user verification or device (and user) verification?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()`, for Google Play it will return `"com.android.vending"` while Amazon Store return `"com.amazon.venezia"`, side-loaded apps will not contain a value.

Comment: No, this way allows to know what store application were downloaded, but I can't be sure application were downloaded exactly by user and not from other device or site.